# flask mysql db.execute loop

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python flask to do a db.execute into a sql database.
I need to do the folloing code for inputs [C4,C5,C6,C7, C8, C9, D7, D8, D9, D4, D5, D6, E7, E8, E9, E4, E5, E6] (So keep replacing C4 with every other input)
Copying and pasting this code below with minimal changes doesn't seem to be efficient, but I cannot find a way to do a loop. How to do a loop for the above list?

```
C4 = request.form.get("C4")
db.execute("UPDATE user_table SET C4 = :C4 WHERE id = :id", id= session["user_id"], C4=C4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update these fields all at once by manually constructing a query (sounds fragile, I agree) collecting the set conditions and query parameters:

```
fields = ["C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D4", "D5", "D6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E4", "E5", "E6"]

query = "UPDATE user_table SET "
conditions = []
params = {}

for field in fields:
    conditions.append(" {field} = :{field} ".format(field=field))
    params[field] = request.form.get(field)

query += ", ".join(conditions) + " WHERE id = :id"
db.execute(query, id=session["user_id"], **params)
```

That `fields` definition though - see if you can avoid hardcoding the list and get it dynamically from the `request.form` object or elsewhere.

Note that we are still properly parameterizing the query (except the column/field names that cannot be parameterized - make sure you trust the source of the `fields` to avoid potential [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

And, look into using ORMs like SQLAlchemy (and since you are using Flask - check out [`Flask-SQLAlchemy`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/)) - updating your models in cases like this would be much simpler, more readable and less error-prone to do with it.